# What's the meaning of this sentence in David Copperfield?

Tags: british-english, literature

Could anyone explain to me about the last sentence "as if a thousand things it makes a noise about, were not one-half so good for it, or me". Who is "it" and so on?

> As I think of them going up and down before those schoolroom windows—the Doctor reading with his complacent smile, an occasional flourish of the manuscript, or grave motion of his head; and Mr. Dick listening, enchained by interest, with his poor wits calmly wandering God knows where, upon the wings of hard words—I think of it as one of the pleasantest things, in a quiet way, that I have ever seen. I feel as if they might go walking to and fro for ever, and the world might somehow be the better for it—as if a thousand things it makes a noise about, were not one-half so good for it, or me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I feel... as if a thousand things [the world] makes a noise about (gets excited about) were not half so good for it (the world), or for me [as this is].

Comment: Thanks very much! Not easy to work it out for me as a non-native speaker!

Answer (score 0):

As I imagine the Doctor and Mr. Dick walking past those schoolroom windows as they used to do *[description omitted]*, my opinion is that it was one of the pleasantest things, in a quiet way, that I have ever seen. [As a consequence] I feel that it would be a good thing if they had continued to do this forever, and, if they had done, then the world might somehow have been a better place—**because I feel that talking about the usual things, as everyone does, is not half as beneficial for people in general, or me (as the sight of the Doctor and Mr. Dick walking past those schoolroom windows.)**

Comment: Thanks very much. But it seems that your interpretation is a bit different from that ofKate Bunting?

Comment: I agree with Kate, Ethan. The difficulty is caused by the fact that two   things are referred to as 'it'. The first is the image of the Doctor and Mr Dick walking past the schoolroom windows and the second is the world. From "-- I think" to "the better for it" the pronoun refers to the image of the Doctor and Mr Dick. From "-- as if a thousand things " onward the pronoun refers to the world. It's the overlap that causes you the problem.